# Trying to insert multiple documents/records into MongoDB via a POST request using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am currently building an API using MongoDB and NodeJS, and I have the following block of code to do a POST request:

```
// '/v1/restaurant/add' - Create
  api.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    let newRestaurant = new Restaurant();
    newRestaurant.name = req.body.name;

    newRestaurant.save(err => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({ message: 'Restaurant saved successfully' });
    });
  });
```

What I would like to do is do a bulk POST (i.e. insert multiple documents/records into my MongoDB at once).  How would I modify my code to accomplish this?

I apologize, but I am very new to JavaScript/NodeJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it using Mongoose.

1. `Model.create()` - it accepts an array of objects to be inserted into the database and does as many queries to the database as the number of items to be inserted. It will be a performance hit if you want to insert lots of records, but you gain the benefit of Mongoose invoking the `save()` method for each of the records which means your `pre` and `post` middleware functions will get triggered. You can read more about the method [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create).
2. `Model.insertMany()` - it also accepts an array of objects to be inserted, but does this in a single database operation. You gain better performance but the trade of is that the `save()` function won't be run for any of the items you want to insert (validations will still be run before submitting the query). You can read more about `insertMany()` [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany).

Personally I would use `create()` if I have to insert less than 50 items at once and if my models are complicated and have `pre/post-save` middleware functions attached to them.

I would use `insertMany()` if my models aren't complicated and I have to regularly insert more than 50 items at a time.